# Extra Bandwidth - Why Still Lag In Games?

Tags: windows-7, bandwidth, gaming, p2p

I have two computers - one for media streaming and one for gaming. My media streaming machine streams using the Asian P2P Media Streaming software Funshion. I've capped my download/upload speed on my media machine to a fraction of the bandwidth my ISP provides me so I have a ton of download/upload bandwidth to spare yet I am still lagging in my online game, such as Battlefield 3 for PC.

I want to note that according to my ping in-game, I am always under 50 ping. I have pinged Google in Command Line and got an average of 24ms. Here is an example of what I see when I lag in Battlefield 3: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpJBwX3GMGg

I've only noticed lag when gaming. When I am streaming Youtube or browsing the Internet off my gaming machine, I do not notice any slow-downs. I've only noticed slow-downs when playing online games.

I also want to add that when my media machine is not streaming, I am lag free in-game.

Media streaming bandwidth cap:

- Download: 100KB/s
- Upload:   15KB/s

ISP bandwidth provided according to Speedtest:

- Download: 1500KB/s
- Upload: 50KB/s

Google ping via Command Line

- Min: 20ms
- Max: 30ms
- Average: 24ms

Comment: Do you play BF3 on PS? or PC?

Comment: Sorry, this is on PC. I will clarify in my post.

Comment: Wired or Wireless?  Could be a router issue not being able to handle the bandwidth (or allocation of bandwidth), regardless of your ISP allotment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to get somewhere like 1MB/s upload before you'll stop lagging. Your isp download speed is fine however, if you only are getting 100KB/s download that is still way to slow to do any kind of online gaming such as Battlefield 3....

Comment: Are you sure that 50KB/s is slow for upload speeds? We are talking kilo-BYTES, not kilo-BITs. I'm pretty sure that speed is fine as I am lag-free in-game when my media machine is not streaming.

Comment: Ok i didnt notice the big B have you run a speed test at www.speedtest.net? thanks.

Comment: I don't mean to sound dis-respectful or rude but I've never had an issue with my upload speed at 50KB/s - even when I have a group (3 or 4) friends over playing Battlefield 3. I am using the Shaw High Speed 20 Bundle http://www.shaw.ca/internet/high-speed-20/. Could there be another problem that is un-related to my bandwidth speed?

Comment: maybe your router? we run a ISP in Canada and our number one customer problem is their routers causing lagg.. we now sell routers and manage them because of the problems that people have with their own... but keep in mind that 100KB/s (killobytes) is only equal to .8MB/s and that if your only getting 15KB/s upload thats only equal to 0.0146484375MB/s...

Comment: Sorry, my media machine is only getting 15KB/s to upload. My ISP provides me with 50KB/s upload. If I understand networking properly, shouldn't the remaining 35KB/s go towards my gaming machine?

Comment: No it doesn't work that way - when you speedtest on your network machine you are getting the full amount of upload speed that you'll get on any other machine in your house..If you carefully looked over shaws plan you would see that it says "Up to 512 Kbps" that doesnt mean that you will always see those speeds. Also keep in note that this is 512Kb (small b) meaning that its only half of 1Mbs..

Comment: I have a Linksys WRT54GL router with Tomato installed. I have enabled QOS following the guide here (http://tomatousb.org/forum/t-639159/qos-random-spikes-in-games).

Comment: i would upgrade your router - the WRT54GL isnt mimo N standard capable meaning that wirless gaming wont be as fast as other routers... I mean really that router is vintage!

Comment: My gaming machine is wired to my router. My media computer is wireless. I'll look into NCIX to see if they have nice routers on sale.

Comment: If you studied your plan carefully you would of seen that it says "up to 512Kbs upload" thats not enough for heavy gaming - if i were you i would upgrade to this plan http://www.shaw.ca/internet/high-speed-25/ keep the leading edge in your games with some serious speed!

Comment: @icu222much - Don't worry about your upload speed all the time. I've been gaming with 2mbps (downstream) too without any major lag. Try pingtest.net, see if that can give you something. Router is pretty OK for such low speeds.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a standard 15mbps ADSL (Or something similar.)
You could try installing [cFosSpeed](http://www.cfos.de/en/cfosspeed/cfosspeed.htm) and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm actually using the Shaw High Speed 20 Bundle. http://www.shaw.ca/internet/high-speed-20/

Comment: I'll try out cFosSpeed :)